# Why is this script failing to run?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For whatever reason ths works when run from console:

```
var wh=window.innerHeight;
var h= wh-345;
$('.hidehome').attr('style', 'display:block;height:'+h+'px;width:100%');
```

but this doesn't:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var wh=window.innerHeight;
var h= wh-345;
$('.hidehome').attr('style', 'display:block;height:'+h+'px;width:100%'); )};
```

I have no idea why. Console tells me

```
Syntax error at line 4: expected expression, got ')'
h+'px;width:100%'); )};
--------------------^
```

Which obviously means something is wrong with my code, but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: the last block `)};` should be `});`

Comment: the ending parenthesis should be '});'. Are you sure this isn't the problem.?

Comment: downvote, because all is written on your console output

Comment: @h4b0: What do you expect to be written?

Comment: @Blender I expect you to read your console output and double check your code

Comment: @h4b0: Sorry, I misread your original comment. Disregard what I said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parenthesis and curly brace need to be switched around:

```
$('.hidehome').attr('style', 'display:block;height:'+h+'px;width:100%'); )};
                                                                         ^^
                                                                     Right here
```

Also, consider using the `css` method:

```
$('.hidehome').css({
    'display': 'block',
    'height': h + 'px',
    'width': '100%'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
)};
```

by this :

```
});
```

You must first close the function definition and after that the call to `document.ready(...)`.

When you have such a problem and you can't find it, try to expand your code with indentations, the problem will be obvious :

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('.hidehome').attr(
            'style',
            'display:block;height:'+h+'px;width:100%'
        );
    ) // <= doesn't match
}; // <= doesn't match
```

In fact I generally prefer to always have this expanded and symmetric form. Code that isn't symmetrically braced hurts me as the structure isn't readable at first glance.